# How to partially rebuild index in Hibernate Search 5.10?

Tags: java, hibernate, elasticsearch, lucene, hibernate-search

I am working on a project where i need to use Hibernate Search and i am gonna index just one entity , it's mapped to a huge table with almost 20 million records and more records daily gonna be added to it but not via the application and entity manager which i am working on and hibernate search can't index new changes automatically. the problem is rebuilding whole index for the entity every day gonna take long time .

I wanted to know is there any way to keep my current index and partially rebuild the index documents for just new changes?

Comment: Hibernate Search appears to support updating: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#manual-index-changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, at the end of the day, you are able to list all the entities that have been modified during the last 24 hours based on information from the database (a date/time of last change for each entity, for example), then yes, there are ways to do that.

First, you can do it "manually" by running your own Hibernate ORM query and calling [`FullTextSession.index`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.10/reference/en-US/html_single/#_adding_instances_to_the_index) on each element you want to see reindexed. You will have to do this in batches, preferably opening a transaction for each batch, if you have a large number of elements to reindex.

Another, better option is to use the [JSR352 integration](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.10/reference/en-US/html_single/#jsr352-integration), which will however require you to use a JSR352-compatible runtime (Spring Batch is not very standard-compliant and won't work; [JBeret](https://github.com/jberet) is known to work). By targeting your single entity and calling `restrictedBy(Criterion)` when building the parameters, you will be able to restrict the list of entities to reindex.

For example:

```
Properties jobProperties = MassIndexingJob.parameters()
        .forEntity( MyClass.class )
        .restrictedBy( Restrictions.ge( "lastChangeDateTime", LocalDate.now().minus( 26, ChronoUnit.HOURS ) ) // 26 to account for DST switch and other slight delays
        .build();
long executionId = BatchRuntime.getJobOperator()
        .start( MassIndexingJob.NAME, jobProperties );
```

The [`MassIndexer`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.10/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-batchindex-massindexer)  unfortunately doesn't offer such feature yet. You can vote for the feature on [ticket HSEARCH-499](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-499) and explain your use case in a comment: we'll try to prioritize features that benefit many users. And of course, you can always reach out to us to discuss how to implement this and contribute a patch :)

Comment: I took first approach , Thank You